# Tensorflow, PyEnvironment: Given `time_step` does not match expected `time_step_spec`

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf-agent

I'm trying to set up a custom PyEnvironment and I get `Given 'time_step' does not match expected 'time_step_spec` error. I don't see where the the dtype specification is missing.

Here's the environment:

```py
class TicTacToe(py_environment.PyEnvironment):

  def __init__(self):
    self._action_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(
        shape=(), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, maximum=1, name='action')
    self._observation_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(
        shape=(1,), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, name='observation')
    self._board = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=np.int32)
    self._state = 0
    self._episode_ended = False
    self._moves = [(i,r) for i in range(3) for r in range(3)]
    self._possiblemoves = self._moves
    self._turn = 0
    self._winner = 0

  def action_spec(self):
    return self._action_spec

  def observation_spec(self):
    return self._observation_spec

  def _reset(self):
    self._state = self._board
    self._episode_ended = False
    return ts.restart(np.array([self._state], dtype=np.int32))

  def _step(self, action):
    if turn % 2 == 0:
      self._player = 1
    else:
      self._player = 2
    if action not in moves:
      raise ValueError("faulty input")
    
    if self._board[action] != 0:
      raise ValueError("spot already taken")
    
    self._board[action] = self._player

    self._possiblemoves = []
    for i in range(3):
      for j in range(3):
        if self._board[i,j] == 0:
            self._possiblemoves.append((i,j))

    for r in range(1,3):
      if self._board[0,0] == self._board[1,1] == self._board[2,2] == r:
          self._winner = r
          break
      elif self._board[0,2] == self._board[1,1] == self._board[2,0] == r:
          self._winner = r
          break
      for j in range(0,3):
          if self._board[0,j] == self._board[1,j] == self._board[2,j] == r:
              self._winner = r
              break
          elif self._board[j,0] == self._board[j,1] == self._board[j,2] == r:
              self._winner = r
    if self._winner == self._player:
      reward = 1
      return ts.termination(np.array([self._state], dtype=np.int32), reward)
    elif self._board.all() != 0:
      reward = 0.5
      return ts.termination(np.array([self._state], dtype=np.int32), reward)
    else:
      return ts.transition(
          np.array([self._state], dtype=np.int32), reward=0.0, discount=1.0)

  def render(self, mode: "human") -> np.ndarray:
    if mode != "human":
      raise ValueError(
          "Only rendering mode supported is 'human', got {} instead.".format(
              mode))
    return self._board
```

Then when I run:

```py
environment = TicTacToe()
utils.validate_py_environment(environment, episodes=1)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Student\Desktop\scripts\tictactoe.ipynb Cell 5' in <cell line: 2>()
      1 environment = TicTacToe()
----> 2 utils.validate_py_environment(environment, episodes=1)

File c:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\environments\utils.py:78, in validate_py_environment(environment, episodes, observation_and_action_constraint_splitter)
     76 while episode_count < episodes:
     77   if not array_spec.check_arrays_nest(time_step, batched_time_step_spec):
---> 78     raise ValueError(
     79         'Given `time_step`: %r does not match expected '
     80         '`time_step_spec`: %r' % (time_step, batched_time_step_spec))
     82   action = random_policy.action(time_step).action
     83   time_step = environment.step(action)

ValueError: Given `time_step`: TimeStep(
{'discount': array(1., dtype=float32),
 'observation': array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]]),
 'reward': array(0., dtype=float32),
 'step_type': array(0)}) does not match expected `time_step_spec`: TimeStep(
{'discount': BoundedArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='discount', minimum=0.0, maximum=1.0),
 'observation': BoundedArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('int32'), name='observation', minimum=0, maximum=2147483647),
 'reward': ArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='reward'),
 'step_type': ArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('int32'), name='step_type')})
```

Where, If I see correctly, the only difference is that

```
'observation': array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]]),
```

Does not have `dtype('int32')` specified, but I can't see why it does not. I sppecified it in observation_spec and I also specified it in board just in case.

Comment: Hi @flowerboy, the error is due to the shape of `self._observation_spec`, changing it to  [1,3,3] will help because the shape of `'observation': array([[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]])` is [1,3,3] . Thank you!

Comment: isnt that what shape he is allready?

Comment: no, i have shape=(1,) in the spec, i will try it out sometimes to see if that fixes it right now i don't have much time